# Webcam not recognized in Dell Mini 10v on Lucid Lynx. How to troubleshoot?

Tags: webcam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [my webcam wont work - how do I debug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3222/my-webcam-wont-work-how-do-i-debug)

Hi, basically I have installed Ubuntu Netbook (10.04) on my Dell Mini 10v (Inspiron 1011) and the webcam does not work. I tried with cheese and skype and they don't see any webcam.

I've been searching in internet but it looks like no one is having problems with the webcam on ubuntu and therefore, I don't find what I can do to fix the problem.

I would appreciate if anyone could help me do it!

Thanks

Edit: Thanks for the comment, this is the otuput of lsusb, it seems it is not detected :S

```
    Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c526 Logitech, Inc. MX Revolution Cordless Mouse
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0158 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Mass Storage Device
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 174f:1403 Syntek 
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: [This](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/q/3222/270) may be a related question (for steps to debug). The first step is to see if the device is detected and any driver is loaded for it. Can you run `lsusb` on a terminal and post its output ?

This should give you a line containing webcam info (model, vendor etc)

Comment: It is working now! I tried what was suggested in the question that you gave me, (checking gstreamer-properties) and I selected "Video for Linux 2" in the video tab, and it works now :) Please, post an answer and i will accept it! Thanks