# Very low webcam framerate in Dell Mini 10

Tags: 10.04, hardware, webcam, dell

The framerate of the built in webcam of my Dell Mini 10 (Inspiron 1010) is extremely slow (may be 1 frame every 10 seconds).

Initially I couldn't see the webcam image. After following the instruction from this previous questions

[Webcam not recognized in Dell Mini 10v on Lucid Lynx. How to troubleshoot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5397/webcam-not-recognized-in-dell-mini-10v-on-lucid-lynx-how-to-troubleshoot)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/3222/my-webcam-wont-work-how-do-i-debug

I executed `gstreamer-properties` and change the Video Default Output from "X Window System (X11/XShm/Xv)" to "X Window System (No Xv)". Now I can see the webcam image, but with a very low frame rate.

Any idea about how to solve this? I am running 10.04

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Exactly the same problem. Surely it can perform better than this.

Of interest, when starting gstreamer-properties I get - 

    gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'atrsdsink'
    gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'esdsink'
    gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'glimagesink'
    gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'sdlvideosink'
    gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'qcamsrc'
    gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'esdmon'

Answer (score 1):

These Dells are becoming famous about it... :-(

Are you using Cheese? Please try changing the default resolution (usually 1024x768), sometimes it's just that. Under Edit -> Preferences, lower it to something like 320x240.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that didn't work. I reduced the resolution down to 160x120, with the same results.